# Label Visit Number based on Date

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a df with site name and date. I want to add a column labeled n_visit. However I want to only label n_visit per site out to the 3rd visit. Once it has reached the 3rd visits I want the label to start again going from 1_visit, 2_visit, 3_visit per site based on date. Essentially I want to know the date window in which 1-3_vistis occurred per site.

My current code is as below. However the mechanism I have used labels some sites out to visit_6 because they were visited a total of 6 times. ultimately I would want to see no more then 3_visit and the labeling starts again. So that one site that was visited 6 times would have two 1-3_visit labels.

```
data <- raw_data %>%
group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(n_visit = match(date, unique(date)),
         n_visit = paste0("visit_", n_visit, sep = ""))
```

```
raw_data <- structure(list(site = c("tryon_weber", "phelps_pond", "phelps_pond", 
"admin_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "admin_pond", "phelps_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "vorisek_pond", "tuttle_pond", "vorisek_pond", 
"vorisek_pond", "rv_pond", "tryon_weber", "tryon_weber", "rv_pond", 
"tryon_weber", "rv_pond"), date = structure(c(19447, 19447, 19452, 
19467, 19480, 19487, 19488, 19492, 19493, 19499, 19500, 19501, 
19506, 19507, 19507, 19508, 19508, 19509, 19513, 19513, 19514, 
19514, 19515, 19515), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Sort the data by site and then date
2. Find the dates which are within `ndays` days of the previous date, for each site. Give every distinct group of these it's own group number
3. For each site and group, give each row a visit number
4. Create a visit group column by making a new group for each site when the visit number equals 1 again
5. Filter to visit groups where there is a 3 in the group

```
library(dplyr)

ndays <- 3

raw_data %>%
  arrange(site, date) |>
  mutate(near = (lag(date, default = first(date)) + ndays < date) |> cumsum(), .by = site) |> 
  mutate(visit = rep(list(1,2,3), length.out = n()), .by = c(site, near)) |>
  mutate(visit_group = cumsum(visit == 1), .by = site) |> 
  filter(3 %in% visit, .by = c(site, visit_group))
```

Output:

```
           site       date near visit visit_group
1       rv_pond 2023-05-22    0     1           1
2       rv_pond 2023-05-23    0     2           1
3       rv_pond 2023-05-24    0     3           1
4       rv_pond 2023-06-05    1     1           2
5       rv_pond 2023-06-06    1     2           2
6       rv_pond 2023-06-07    1     3           2
7   tryon_weber 2023-06-05    1     1           2
8   tryon_weber 2023-06-06    1     2           2
9   tryon_weber 2023-06-07    1     3           2
10  tuttle_pond 2023-05-29    0     1           1
11  tuttle_pond 2023-05-30    0     2           1
12  tuttle_pond 2023-05-31    0     3           1
13 vorisek_pond 2023-05-30    0     1           1
14 vorisek_pond 2023-05-31    0     2           1
15 vorisek_pond 2023-06-01    0     3           1
```

Comment: Interesting approach and this seems to work. However I would still like to have a column that has n_visit with the visit number labeled as it will be needed for some pivoting label.

Comment: step is the visit # apologies for the strange column name

Comment: no worries! just looking at the output right now, it seems like the data needed to be sorted (see: rows 19 to 21

Comment: how would we filter out any visits that did not have visit_1-3 occur in the given time period?

Comment: @Eizy updated it, check it out

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on all this wrangling

Comment: no worries! if you want to mark it solved I'd appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `%%` (modulus) for this.

```r
library(dplyr)
raw_data %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(
    n_visit = match(date, unique(date)),
    n_visit = paste0("visit_", (n_visit - 1) %% 3 + 1, sep = "")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 24 × 3
#    site          date       n_visit
#    <chr>         <date>     <chr>  
#  1 tryon_weber   2023-03-31 visit_1
#  2 phelps_pond   2023-03-31 visit_1
#  3 phelps_pond   2023-04-05 visit_2
#  4 admin_pond    2023-04-20 visit_1
#  5 wood_lab_pond 2023-05-03 visit_1
#  6 admin_pond    2023-05-10 visit_2
#  7 phelps_pond   2023-05-11 visit_3
#  8 wood_lab_pond 2023-05-15 visit_2
#  9 wood_lab_pond 2023-05-16 visit_3
# 10 rv_pond       2023-05-22 visit_1
# # ℹ 14 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The `(n_visit - 1)` is because modulus is 0-based, so with `visit_4` it would convert to `visit_0`, not what we want. So we subtract one so that visit `1` will be `0`, and `0 %% 3` is still `0` (and `3 %% 3` is `0` as well). We compensate for that with `+ 1` after the modulus.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't use .by ! 

Comment: Why? There are definitely advantages to _not_ using `.by=` (though none present here, afaict), and I was mimicking the OP's original code. @Mark

Comment: brevity is the soul of wit and all :P

Comment: This works thank you. However would you know what would need to be done in order to start the counting/labeling over by say a time delay? For example if you look at tryon_weber on 2023-03-31 that is labeled as visits_1, which is correct. However between 2023-06-05 to 07 it was repeat visited. Ultimately I more interested in data points that are repeat visited 3 times. So would you know a way to add a lag if say more then 3 days occur with out visiting that site the labeling of n_visit starts over?

Comment: Okay, I get the date-delay thing, how would daily for 7 days running work?

Comment: So with this or the code below by @Mark how would we filter out any visits that did not have visit_1-3 occur in the given time period?

Comment: Likely a combination of `group_by(.)` and `filter(all(c("visit_1", ...) %in% n_visit))`

Comment: I see what your mean but where I am lost is some how we have to take the rows in which to keep that have had visits_1, visit_2, and visit_3 where they have occurred in repeat visits (back to back to back days)