# How to pivot table without getting list columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Struggling to figure out the correct way to pivot this df correctly. I have a table with the colunmns as below in the dput. I want the output table to have column headers: "site", "visit_1", "visit_2", and "visit_3" with the values associated in reach row of "n" be populated under the correct column.

| site | visit_1 | visit_2 | visit_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab_1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| ab_2 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| ac_1 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| ac_2 | 4 | 2 | 5 |

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19447, 19447, 19452, 19452, 
19467, 19467, 19480, 19480, 19488, 19488, 19488, 19492, 19492, 
19492, 19493, 19493, 19499, 19499, 19500, 19500, 19500, 19501, 
19501, 19506, 19506, 19506, 19507, 19507, 19507, 19507, 19507, 
19507, 19508, 19508, 19508, 19508, 19508, 19509, 19513, 19513, 
19513, 19514, 19514, 19514, 19515, 19515, 19515, 19515, 19515
), class = "Date"), site = c("tryon_weber_obs_1", "tryon_weber_obs_2", 
"phelps_pond_obs_1", "phelps_pond_obs_2", "admin_pond_obs_1", 
"admin_pond_obs_2", "wood_lab_pond_obs_1", "wood_lab_pond_obs_2", 
"phelps_pond_obs_1", "phelps_pond_obs_2", "phelps_pond_obs_3", 
"wood_lab_pond_obs_1", "wood_lab_pond_obs_2", "wood_lab_pond_obs_3", 
"wood_lab_pond_obs_1", "wood_lab_pond_obs_2", "rv_pond_obs_1", 
"rv_pond_obs_2", "rv_pond_obs_1", "rv_pond_obs_2", "rv_pond_obs_3", 
"rv_pond_obs_1", "rv_pond_obs_2", "tuttle_pond_obs_1", "tuttle_pond_obs_2", 
"tuttle_pond_obs_3", "tuttle_pond_obs_1", "tuttle_pond_obs_2", 
"tuttle_pond_obs_3", "tuttle_pond_obs_4", "vorisek_pond_obs_1", 
"vorisek_pond_obs_2", "tuttle_pond_obs_1", "tuttle_pond_obs_2", 
"vorisek_pond_obs_1", "vorisek_pond_obs_2", "vorisek_pond_obs_3", 
"vorisek_pond_obs_1", "rv_pond_obs_1", "tryon_weber_obs_1", "tryon_weber_obs_2", 
"rv_pond_obs_1", "tryon_weber_obs_1", "tryon_weber_obs_2", "rv_pond_obs_1", 
"rv_pond_obs_2", "tryon_weber_obs_1", "tryon_weber_obs_2", "tryon_weber_obs_3"
), n = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 17L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), n_visit = c("visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", 
"visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", 
"visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_2", 
"visit_2", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_2", 
"visit_3", "visit_3", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_2", 
"visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_3", 
"visit_3", "visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_3", "visit_1", 
"visit_1", "visit_1", "visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_2", "visit_3", 
"visit_3", "visit_3", "visit_3", "visit_3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-49L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: ```data %>% 
  group_by(site, n_visit) %>% 
  summarise(n_sum = sum(n)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = site, names_from = n_visit, values_from = n_sum, values_fill = c(n_sum = 0))```

Comment: You have multiple rows for the same site. How do you wanna handle those? In my comment above, I summed the number of visits by site and n_visit. Otherwise, we'll end up with list columns because the rows are not unique.

Comment: Is it possible that you want to "group" triplets of visits together? Your last question included the notion of "days gap", which suggests that you might want groups of visit triplets. If that's the case, it would help reduce the one-to-many mapping in this pivot.

Comment: hmm ya does seem to be the issues. I want to group triplets of visits together I believe. Ya so i think if we could group by triplet visits and have those pivoted correctly based on each time a site and observer (rv_pond_obs_1) had 3 visits with the counts in the correct column/row per visit.

Comment: are you wanting to use the output of the answer to your previous question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Label Visit Number based on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053562/label-visit-number-based-on-date)