# How Create Variable Indicating Survey Period Based on Visits

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame as below. The code provided below creates a a column for visits number based on the date of arrival per site. But starts counting visit number again if 3 days has passed since the last visits. How would I add another column in which would indicate which survey period that period of counting started?

I imagine a second column called "survey_period". And For example: The site "wood_lab_pond" was visited on the "2023-05-03", "2023-05-15", "2023-05-16". So the survey_period column would indicate a "1" for the row with "2023-05-03" but then a "2" for the rows with "2023-05-15", "2023-0516".

Desired table output Sample

| site | date | n_visit | survey_period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wood_lab_pond | 2023-05-03 | visit_1 | 1 |
| wood_lab_pond | 2023-05-15 | visit_1 | 2 |
| wood_lab_pond | 2023-05-16 | visit_2 | 2 |

```
ndays <- 3

data <- raw_data%>% 
  mutate(near = (lag(date, default = first(date)) + ndays < date) |> cumsum(), 
         .by = site) %>%  
  mutate(n_visit = rep(list(1,2,3), length.out = n()), .by = c(site, near),
         n_visit = paste("visit_", n_visit, sep=""))
```

```
raw_data <- structure(list(site = c("tryon_weber", "phelps_pond", "phelps_pond", 
"admin_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "admin_pond", "phelps_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "vorisek_pond", "tuttle_pond", "vorisek_pond", 
"vorisek_pond", "rv_pond", "tryon_weber", "tryon_weber", "rv_pond", 
"tryon_weber", "rv_pond"), date = structure(c(19447, 19447, 19452, 
19467, 19480, 19487, 19488, 19492, 19493, 19499, 19500, 19501, 
19506, 19507, 19507, 19508, 19508, 19509, 19513, 19513, 19514, 
19514, 19515, 19515), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: I think I answered this in the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77053732/4145280

Comment: Yes you did. I did not see the udpate. Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Label Visit Number based on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053562/label-visit-number-based-on-date)